# Laravel dynamic routing for search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to generate dynamic route when user clicks on `Search` button.

I know it can be done with following `GET` method

```
https://laravel.dev/search?q=parameter 
https://laravel.dev/search?state=XYZ&category=Automobile
```

But instead I would like to do following

```
https://laravel.dev/search/state/XYZ/category/Automobile
```

So if I add an extra parameter in search form it will just add onto the URL.

The parameters may be optional so can not add a fix route in `routes`. User may supply state or search through all states.

```
https://laravel.dev/search/category/Automobile
```

Following is my search form code

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <!--Search Bar-->
    {{ html()->form('GET',route('frontend.search'))->class('form-inline justify-content-center')->open() }}
    {{ html()->select('category',$categories)->class('form-control mr-sm-2') }}

    {{ html()->select('state',$states)->class('form-control mr-sm-2') }}

    <!--More filter to add later-->
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

    {{ html()->form()->close() }}
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `Route::get('search/{searchString?}', 'searchController@search')
    ->where('searchString', '(.*)');` and use middleware to handle $searchString?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the logic with a catch-all route with regular expressions
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

```
//routes.php
Route::get('search/{search?}', 'SearchController@search')
    ->where('search', '(.*)');


//controller 
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function search($search = null)
    {
        if ($search != null){   
            dd($search);          
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I did try that but $searchString is always null

Comment: what should the search form look like now? If `{search}` is not optional then I have to pass something to `route('frontend.search',{ $search })`.

Comment: I have added my search form in the question.

Comment: I edited the post again to put back the optional part - FYI, the previous issue (always return null) was due to the camel case in `searchString`

Comment: it still receives null

Comment: Must be a different issue - it's working fine in my project.. Could you have routes clashing ? Maybe an existing `search/...` route?

Comment: nope just this one. I tried changing it from `/search` to something else as well.

Comment: I added a picture of what I get - I can't figure out what is your other problem

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I will try again with completely new controller and new path name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Regex:

```
Route::get('search/{searchParams}', 'SearchController@search')
    ->where('searchParams', '[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+');
```

You can put anything on `searchParams` but you need to parse it.